# Can I use a lower voltage power supply to power a router?

Tags: voltage, power-supply

Devices in question:
Power supply: 5V 2A USB charger with 2 ports
Router: 10V 1A
Modem: 10V 0.5A

I'm trying to decrease the volume of cables and I'm pondering about removing my router and modem's chargers and use a single plug with two outputs. But the only spare plug I have here has a 5V voltage while both devices specify 10V.

Is it plausible to power one of them? If yes, what about both?

I'd like to understand the risks and what kind of power supply I'd need to power both devices if not plausible

Comment: Electronics are usually quite picky about the voltage they get.  Where the USB and router both supply the same wattage, Quite sure only half the voltage would make the router go weird.  Would probably use a decent powersurge strip and plug the router and modem into it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It's not about home improvement .

Comment: there are cheap cables that go from usb to 9v and 12v DC plugs on ebay et al.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it plausible to power one of them? If yes, what about both?

You can't power either of them.

> I'd like to understand the risks

They won't work. If they have the same polarity DC power connectors (i.e. both centre-positive or both centre-negative) you can use a single 10 V power supply rated at 1.5 amps. It's acceptable for the power supply to have a greater current rating but it must have a 10 V voltage output.

However using the existing device power supplies with a suitable power strip to provide more sockets is the most straightforward option. There are various wiring accessories available to tidy up stray cables. It's safer to bundle low voltage DC cables separately from AC power cables, and is required by wiring code in some jurisdictions.

Comment: Consider ways of organizing, rather than eliminating, power supplies and wires.  Some velcro straps to tidy the wires, and a chain of very short single-outlet [*piggyback* extension cords](https://amazon.com/CyberPower-GC201-Heavy-Duty-Extension/dp/B01JRLSPRW/ref=sr_1_4), rather than a power bar, provide a neater arrangement.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR No

Generally speaking, with any power supply, you need to match:

- AC vs. DC
- Voltage - must be within range of the device specifications. If the device just specifies a single value, you can typically vary a bit - 5% up or down is reasonable (and in fact normally required for 120V or 240V *nominal* powered devices) but not 50%.
- Current - the power supply must be able to supply *at least as much* as the specs of the device being powered. More is OK - the device will just get what it needs.
- Connector - historically, most connectors were 2 or 3-wire connectors of some sort, and you just had to figure out +/- (if DC), ground (if relevant). But a USB connector is actually a bit more complicated, or at least it can be. But in any case, the usual USB adapter is, by definition, a 5V supply. USB C can have higher voltage, but that is not simply "plug it in to any device and get higher voltage".

The end result is that a USB adapter, *or any other power adapter that produces 5V output* can't supply 10V. And any device that requires 10V can't run on 5V.

Answer (score 1):

5v won't power the 10v router, and the 10v will blow the 5v appliance. You may be able to buy, or make a 10v>5v voltage dropper, but you'll still have to plug each in separately, to separate outlets. And that's without considering the polarity of each, which is important when dealing with D.C.

They're separate entities, and will have to be kept separate, sorry.

Cutting down on *mains* leads is simpler - use one cable, with a kettle socket on its end, and replace all your appliance leads with kettle plugs on short cables. I did this 50 yrs ago, and it saves the snakes nest, and a lot of tidying up after a job: you can only use one tool at a time. Of course, battery power has made it almost redundant now.